# add tabindex attribute to a class mark dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, textangular

I am new to `angularjs`. I am using a `textangular` to show a html document. I want to highlight some words from that html and also want to focus that word.So, I am using `tabindex` and `class = mark` to highlight and focus. So, Here At first I am adding

```
<span class="mark">ABC</span>
```

so that It will get highlighted, after that I want to add a `tabindex=1` attribute to this .So that It become like

```
<span class="mark" tabindex="1">ABC</span>
```

Here I want to add this `tabindex` dynamically. That means , I want to find that text and then add a `tabindex` to that text only.How can I achieve this ?At a time tabindex can be applied to only one word.

Comment: you want to set focus to the first instance of the word? or you want the focus to go to the word when the user presses `tab`?

Comment: No Its not when user presses tab. I have an array of words which I need to highlight and focus and I have a Next button on which only that word should get highlighted and focused.It's just not for a single word.

Comment: then you don't need `tabindex`, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `contains()` like this.
Change `span` to `a` to get default `href` highlighter.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("a.mark:contains('ABC')").attr("tabindex", 1);
  $("a.mark1:contains('ABC')").attr("tabindex", 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="mark" href="#">ABC</a>
<a class="mark1" href="#">ABC</a>
<button>Next</button>
```

Comment: Hi, this one is working but It's not focusing that word.

Comment: `href` is not a valid attribute on a `<span>`

Comment: Hey, I have just used  $("span.mark:contains("+text+")").attr("tabindex", -1).focus();  . then It starts focusing as well.

Comment: @MoinZaman Yes I know but he is using `span` only right. He can customize like that or else he can use `a` for valid html markup.

Comment: @JohnR i would not use invalid HTML as much as possible. Might cause weird issues. Also for others who see this answer might think that `href` is valid on a `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

`.focus()` or keyboard navigating / tabindexing `<span>`'s is not reliable.

You need to use empty hyperlink tags, like so:

`<a href="#" onCLick="return false" class="mark">ABC</a>`

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("a.mark:contains('ABC')").focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onCLick="return false" class="mark">ABC</a>
<a href="#" onCLick="return false" class="mark1">ABC1</a>
<button>Next</button>
```

Comment: I have a html document so here  $(".mark").is(":contains("+text+")")  it is returning false.